# How to increment field value in sqlx

Tags: go, sqlx

In a Go app, using `sqlx` package and mysql database, I want to update table `user` and increment its `posts` field by 1:

```
err = shared.Dbmap.Exec("UPDATE user SET posts=posts+1 WHERE id=?", userId)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

However at compile time I get:

> multiple-value shared.Dbmap.DB.Exec() in single-value context

I looked at [the docs](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) and could not see relevant examples.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to read the *actual* [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#NamedStmt.Exec), not just the github package summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to read the message `multiple-value shared.Dbmap.DB.Exec() in single-value context`:

- `shared.Dbmap.DB.Exec()` has multiple values
- You are trying to use it in a single-value context

In your code you have `err = shared.Dbmap.Exec(...)`.

On the left side of the assignment there is a single value,
on the right side there are multiple.

Looking at the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Execer), the `Exec(...)` function returns 2 values,
but you assign it to one value.

Write like this:

```
_, err = shared.Dbmap.Exec("UPDATE user SET posts=posts+1 WHERE id=?", userId)
```